# How to list salt minions by compound matching in template?

Tags: salt-stack

I would like to list all minions that match my compound targeting string. I have already looked at this question [How to get a list of all salt minions in a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158665/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-salt-minions-in-a-template) but my question is a little bit different as I need to use compound matching. Also I may be hitting this bug: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/18878

Take as example below template:

```
{% for host in salt['publish.publish']('G@roles:hadoop_master', 'network.interfaces', expr_form='compound') %}
echo {{ host }}:
  cmd.run
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is that it's not showing any data.

While the following template is working as expected:

```
{% for host in salt['publish.publish']('*', 'network.interfaces') %}
echo {{ host }}:
  cmd.run
{% endfor %}
```

I have also tried using the mine:

```
{% for host, hostinfo in salt['mine.get']('G@roles:hadoop_master', 'network.interfaces', 'compound').items() %}
echo {{ host }}:
  cmd.run
{% endfor %}
```

I have done all nessecary prequisites to setup mine and peer/publish. This is enabled on master /etc/salt/master:

```
peer:
  .*:
    - network.ip_addrs
    - network.interfaces
```

And following config is on minion /etc/salt/minion:

```
mine_functions:
    network.interfaces: []
    network.ip_addrs: []
    grains.items: []
```

Comment: Have you tried testing your compound matcher from the master?

`salt -C 'G@roles:hadoop_master' network.interfaces`

Comment: Sorry for forgetting to answer the question. There is a known bug so it was disabled for mine and peer. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the answer from whiteinge https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/18878#issuecomment-66865740:

Compound matching for Mine and Peer was disabled in 2014.7.0 and will be re-enabled in 2014.7.1. See the note at the top of the release notes:

http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/releases/2014.7.0.html