# Get minions IP inside a salt template filtered by grains

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18117679/839049) that tells how to get the IP of another minions inside a template but i can't get `host.fqdn` or `host.ip`. When I use `host` I get the full domain name and not the IP. When I ran it on console it gets the ips, but inside the template it does return a `str object`

```
Unable to manage file: Jinja variable 'str object' has no attribute 'fqdn'
```

I tried this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17180898/839049) but this one didn't even show a result.

I want to be able to build a hosts file. Each minion have some roles set as grains, like this:

```
roles:
  - backend
  - cdn
  - ...
```

I want to be able to get all `roles:backend and not roles:cdn`. But when I added this line to my `publish.publish` I get this error:

```
Unable to manage file: Jinja error: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, I added the peer publish on master but it doesn't work. I've read the docs and they don't help me find the problem.

**EDIT** **Versions report**

```
   $ salt-minion --versions-report
                 Salt: 2015.5.3
               Python: 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56)
               Jinja2: 2.7.2
             M2Crypto: 0.21.1
       msgpack-python: 0.3.0
         msgpack-pure: Not Installed
             pycrypto: 2.6.1
              libnacl: Not Installed
               PyYAML: 3.10
                ioflo: Not Installed
                PyZMQ: 14.0.1
                 RAET: Not Installed
                  ZMQ: 4.0.4
                 Mako: Not Installed
              Tornado: Not Installed
Debian source package: 2015.5.3+ds-1trusty1
```

**EDIT 2 the sls snippet**

```
{% for host in salt['publish.publish']('roles:backend', 'network.ip_addrs', 'eth0', 'grain') %}
  server {{ host.ip }}; # {{ host.fqdn }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of  `salt-minion --versions-report`? That will help me reproduce the issue you're having.

Comment: Added as an edit, could you take a look?

Comment: Also, could you include a snippet of your sls file that when run will give the error you're running into?

Comment: added the snippet, the problem happens because the var returned, `host` , is a string and doesn't have `ip` or `fqdn`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution:

Inside a minion config add this piece of code:

```
mine_interval: 2
mine_functions:
  network.ip_addrs:
    - eth1 # or any other eth-n you might want
```

To match all backends and not the load_balancers we need a compound matcher

```
G@roles:backend and not G@roles:load_balancer
```

After that just put it all together in the template using `salt.mine`

```
{%- for server, addrs in salt['mine.get']('G@roles:backend and not G@roles:load_balancer', 'network.ip_addrs', 'compound').items() %}
  # {{ server }}
  server {{ addrs|last }};
{%- endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

`network.ip_addrs` doesn't give you the fqdn. It only gives you a list of ip address.

```
[boucha@elsapo ~]$ sudo salt dasalt network.ip_addrs --out json
{
    "dasalt": [
        "10.0.3.1", 
        "10.4.156.81", 
        "172.17.42.1"
    ]
}
```

Comment: In my snippet I can get only the `dasalt`. I need to get the IP. I don't care about the `fqdn` in the start of the question I stated that the answer I found is said to gather the `ip` and `fqdn` but my experiments returned only the `fqdn` in a diferent way the original answer did