# Get minion ip in Saltstack Jinja template filtered by pillar

Tags: automation, jinja2, salt-stack

I'm currently busy creating a automated netdata ephemeral cluster, which means I have a master netdata node which the slaves connect to. 
I've found a similar [question + answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31758639/get-minions-ip-inside-a-salt-template-filtered-by-grains), but instead of using a grain I use pillars.

I'm trying to get the Netdata master ip, and distribute it to the minions running Netdata via a Template. But this can be applied to other master-slave configs as well (e.g. postgres, elasticsearch etc)

I'm assigning roles via pillars. 
So my pillar file looks like:

```
server:
  roles:
    - netdata-master
    - grafana
```

And my jinja template:

```
{% set netdatamaster = ..... %}
[stream]
  # stream metrics to another netdata
  enabled = yes

  # the IP and PORT of the master
  destination = {% netdatamaster %}:19999
```

Now I want the var `netdatamaster` to contain the ipv4 adres of the Netdata master. I just can't figure out a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Salt Mine for this.

First add a mine_function to your netdata-master server. This can be configured in pillar or in the minion config file.

```
mine_functions:
  eth0_ip_addrs:
    mine_function: network.ip_addrs
    interface: eth0
```

The above mine_function enables other minions to request the value of `network.ip_addrs` for your netdata-master server.

You can request this data in different ways:

- From the cli:
  `salt 'other_minion_id' mine.get 'netstat-master_id' eth0_ip_addrs`
- In your state files:
  `{{ salt['mine.get']('netstat-master_id', 'eth0_ip_addrs') }}`

In your case you can put it in the top of your Jinja template file.
`{% set netdatamaster = salt['mine.get']('netstat-master_id', 'eth0_ip_addrs') %}`